# Issue installing fancyimpute on a Windows computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, fancyimpute

I got this to work on my Mac before but can't seem to get it working on Windows. I am trying to install the fancyimpute package for python but I get an error message after typing:

```
pip install fancyimpute
```

I get .... line 1175, in_REalGetContents raise BedZipFile("File is not a zip file") zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file).

I also tried another answer's attempts using:
    conda install ecos
    conda install CVXcanon

and then doing the pip install fancyimpute but that didn't help either.

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 141, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 299, in run
resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
self.require_hashes
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement
progress_bar=self.progress_bar
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\download.py", line 823, in unpack_url
unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\download.py", line 728, in unpack_file_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 578, in unpack_file
flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\p
ip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 463, in unzip_file
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", 
li
ne 1108, in __init__
self._RealGetContents()
File "c:\users\mkheifetz\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", 
li
ne 1175, in _RealGetContents
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Please add the complete traceback for further assistance and also show what version of python and pip you are using for reproducibility.

Comment: ok I put the traceback in my question.